# Best practice for recreating a set of tables while keeping them available?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

Every few weeks we get revised set of customer data. This is not an incremental batch, but a complete from-scratch set. I have a set of SSIS packages that create large sets of customer metadata from this source data. These are sets pretty complex, and don't work as views for performance reasons so the SSIS packages create tables from the views. The tables have several indexes and they work pretty well.

EDIT:[the reason renaming the table is a problem is that when I rename the table, I no longer have an empty new table to add data to next time. So I have to create it from scratch, which means the table definition is stored in either a proc or local file. The thing is, these tables and the data they contain are under constant development (it's marketing data, so we're always coming up with new metrics to put on customers) and so columns are changed and added between releases. I'd like to limit the number of places I have to make these changes. Right now it's change the view, change the SSIS package, and change the target table.]

The first problem is the SSIS packages take a loooong time to run, and while they are running, each table is offline in turn, and each table that hasn't yet been updated doesn't match those that have, so the set (which are often used together) behave pretty wonky while the packages are running. EDIT: [This is because the customer id's change somewhat with each release of data. So, joining an old-release table to a new-release table means data from two different customers is being joined together.]

I'm trying to figure out how to do this while keeping the tables available.

Current method: Truncate old tables, add new records, rebuild indexes. Takes way too long.

Idea #1: Create new tables, rebuild indexes, drop old tables, rename new tables to old table names. The renaming should be very fast. The problem is that renaming removes the table structure for the new tables, so I then have to recreate the table structures (including indexes) the next time I want to run the process. There is no easy way to do this via sql, or even in SSIS. It means keeping the table structure definition in a local file rather in the DB...doesn't sound good.

Idea #2: Truncate & reload new tables, rebuild indexes, copy them to new, new tables, then drop old and rename the new, new tables. This leaves the first set of new tables for future  Of course the problem here is we have three times the space taken up, and copying tables takes a fair bit of time.

Idea #3: Make new tables, truncate old tables, insert data into old tables, rebuild indexes. This will likely take as much time as the current method or #1.

What is a best practice for this kind of thing? Are there other methods I'm missing?

EDIT: [Using SQL Server 2008, not sure if it's enterprise edition or not. I do not have admin access to the server, so many things, like running SSIS packages on the server, are not available.]

Comment: is merging old tables with new data an option? either using `MERGE` or by deleting existing records from the newly imported table, then appending leftovers to the old table?

Comment: I don't understand the downside of idea 1.  `sp_RENAME '[OldTableName]' , '[NewTableName]'` preserves table structure including indexes.

Comment: Enterprise edition or not? How are people accessing the data and getting wonky results when the data load is being performed?

Comment: I have added to the question to answer your questions.

Comment: You don't need to be an admin, just the ability to run a query to determine version and edition `SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS ProductVersion
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel') AS ProductLevel
,   SERVERPROPERTY ('edition') AS Edition;`

Comment: Product version is 10.50.4000.0, level is SP2, Edition is Standard Edition (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SQL Database Snapshots feature.  This preserves a snapshot of your database at a point in time, which your users can happily query while you are updating in the background.

You do need an astounding amount of free disk space, as the Snapshot files grow and grow the longer you try to hold onto the snapshot (while updating the underlying database). It's otherwise fairly straightforward to set up and use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175158.aspx

Comment: Read through the link quickly - am I correct in understanding that the snapshot would essentially be the full time source for this data, and would exist full time?  What I mean is, I have the database, and then a snapshot called database_snapshot. Processes that had been referencing database.table1, etc, would now have to reference database_snapshot.table1..correct?

Comment: Typically the snapshot exists almost full time - you refresh it at the end of your ETL process.  It becomes the source for reporting and analysis processes.  Your ETL processes would continue against the current database.

Answer (score -1):

> Are there other methods I'm missing?

1. Create new tables and load new data on a different server, a different instance, or a different schema.
2. Switch servers, or instances, or schemas.